Some standard properties of Lebesgue integral
I have to prove the following theorem as exercise.
Theorem. Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure, $f,g:X\to [0,+\infty)$ two measurable functions and $A,B\in \mathcal{M}$.
Then, the following facts hold:
(1) If $f\leq g$, then $\int_X f\ d\mu \leq \int_X g\ d\mu$.
(2) If $A\subseteq B$, then $\int_A f\ d\mu \leq \int_B f\ d\mu$.
(3) If $f(x)=0,  \forall x\in A$, then $\int_A f \ d\mu=0$, even if $\mu(A)=+\infty$.
Proof.
My fault is on point $(3)$. My attempt is the following:
(3)
Suppose $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^k A_n$ where $A_n\in \mathcal{M}, \hspace{3pt} \forall n\in\{1,...,k\}$ and $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ if $i\ne j$.
So, a simple function that approximates $f$ it's like that $s=\sum_{n=1}^k a_n\mathbf{1}_{A_n}$, therefore, I have that $$\int_A s\ d\mu =\sum_{n=1}^k a_n \mu(A_n)$$
Now, I have that:
$$\int_A f\ d\mu=\sup\left\{\int_A s \ d\mu, \hspace{5pt} s\hspace{5pt} \mbox{simple function}, \hspace{5pt} 0\leq s\leq f\right\}=$$ $$=\sup\left\{\int_A s \ d\mu, \hspace{5pt} s\hspace{5pt} \mbox{simple function}, \hspace{5pt} 0\leq s\leq 0\right\}=$$ $$=\sup\left\{\int_A s \ d\mu, \hspace{5pt} s\hspace{5pt} \mbox{simple function}, \hspace{5pt} s=0\right\}=(\ast)$$
From the previous observation, I obtain that:
$$s=0 \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^k a_n\mathbf{1}_{A_n}=0 \Longleftrightarrow \forall n\in \{1,...,k\}, \hspace{3pt}  a_n=0 \vee 1_{A_n}=0$$
So, $$\int_A s\ d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^k a_n \mu(A_n)=0$$ and in conclusion:
$$\int_A f\ d\mu =(\ast)=0$$
How can I complete the discussion about $s=0$?

Your proof is complete!

Yes, but I want to formalize why $1_{A_n}=0$ iimplies that $\mu(A_n)=0$.

$1_{A_n}=0\iff A_n=\varnothing.$

Yes, certainly!! It was quite obvious but I thought about it for two hours, thank you very much!
